# Get Photos from a Facebook page and display it in my view in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I need to get the photos from a Facebook page and need to display it in my view? Is it possible in IOS. if it is possible how to do it? I googled and found no clue.

Update:I need to display pictures from the album.

Comment: Check out here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and here: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: need to display profile  picture?

Comment: @NaCLNo I need to display pictures frm the album.